# Which of the following options are correct?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$f(x),g(x)$ are defined on $[-1,1]$, $f'(0),g'(0)$ exist, $f(0)=g(0)$, and $f(x)\ge g(x)$ holds for an open interval containing $0$. Then which of the following is correct:

I, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same tangent line at $(0,0)$;

II, $f'(0)\ge g'(0)$;

III, $g''(0)$ exists

$2$nd option is true

$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x\geq\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}x=g'(0)$

How we can prove or disprove the other two options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h=f-g$. This function is non negative in an open interval containing $0$ and $h(0)=0$. Moreover, $h$ is derivable at $x=0$. Since $h$ meets a minimum at $0$, then $h'(0)=0$, that is $f'(0)=g'(0)$. Therefore, $f$ and $g$ have the same tangent line at $x=0$.

For the third point take for example $f(x)=2x^2$, $g(x)=x|x|$.

Comment: Ok so only 3rd option is false,thanks